# Swift: Sort Core Data array in a function

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, core-data

I have an array of objects from Core Data that I would like to sort in a function in a child view. I know how to sort using `.sorted(by:{})`, but the problem is assigning the sorted array back to the ObservedObject variable so the UI updates with the sorted data.

In the code below, when I try to do `habits = habits.sorted(by:{})`, I get the following errors:

1. Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
2. Mark method 'mutating' to make 'self' mutable
3. Cannot assign value of type '[FetchedResults.Element]' (aka 'Array') to type 'FetchedResults'

Does anyone know a better way to do this or how to resolve the error?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Habit.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Habit.id, ascending: true)]) var habits: FetchedResults<Habit>
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(habits, id: \.self) { habit in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(habit.title)
                            HStack {
                                ForEach(habit.dayArray.count-7..<habit.dayArray.count, id: \.self) { index in
                                    DayView(day: habit.dayArray[index], habits: self.habits)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    struct DayView: View {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
        @ObservedObject var day: Day
        var habits: FetchedResults<Habit>
        var body: some View {
            Text(“\(day.wrappedShort)“).onTapGesture {
                self.sortHabits(day: self.day)
            }
        }
        func sortHabits() {
            self.habits = habits.sorted{ $0.title.uppercased() < $1.title.uppercased() }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a NSSortDescriptor to your fetch request instead?

Comment: Your sortHabits is strange, it takes a parameter that isn't used and calling `moc.save()` will not have any effect on the sort order if that is what you believe

Comment: Thanks Joakim, re: the NSSortDescriptor, I tried this but I want to sort after the fetch. The app I'm building is to check off daily habits, so once the user has marked off a habit for the day, I want that habit to go to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Re: the sortHabits function, I tried to simplify the code block as much as possible for my question but left in those inconsistencies accidentally. I'll update the original question code now.

Comment: But if you update one habit won't the @FetchRequest update automatically?

Comment: Damn, I wrote a test yesterday to re-sort based on a change in the habit.title and it didn't work, but just wrote another one to make sure, and you're right. The @FetchRequest sorts automatically with a change. But now I need to figure out how to sort by a child value in the parent/habit array... any ideas?